# Prove that uniform convergence almost everywhere implies convergence almost uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, uniform-convergence, almost-everywhere

How can I prove the following result?

> Uniform convergence almost everywhere implies convergence almost uniformly.

I know Egorov's theorem which says pointwise convergence almost everywhere implies convergence almost uniformly when measure of domain is finite.
Also, uniform convergence almost everywhere implies pointwise convergence almost everywhere. But Egorov's theorem applies only for finite measure domain.
That means from the result written above, we can conclude that finite measure domain is not required in case of uniform convergence almost everywhere.

Comment: What is almost uniformly? I thought that was the same as uniform convergence a.e

Comment: Uniform convergence a.e. implies almost uniform convergence, trivially. Egorov has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @DionelJaime it means uniform convergence off a set of small measure (as small as desired (but not  0, necessarily)).

Comment: I see. But then it is indeed trivial. If you have uniform convergence on a set $E$ then you certainly have it for any subset of $E$.

Comment: Oh yes! I was a fool to not realize it initially. Now I see that it is indeed very trivial. Thanks for the comments.